# Understanding VSC++ linker errors

Tags: c, visual-studio, linker

I'm trying to build a simple command line application which uses WinUSB in Visual Studio 2013. I'm getting no compile errors, but lots of linker errors. The following are some of them:

```
winusblnk.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol imp__Sleep@4 referenced in function _msDelay 
winusbnet.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__Sleep@4
```

What do the references to obj files mean? How do I see these OBJ files? How can I inspect them and see what functions they have inside them?

What does `__imp__Sleep@4` mean? What do all the underscores mean? What does the `@4` mean? How do I find the reference to this symbol?

What is the difference between error `LNK2019` and error `LINK2001`?

There are lots more similar errors in `winusbxxx.obj` files.

```
errhnd.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__GetLocalTime@4 referenced in function _logerr 
readtemp.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _ReadTemperature referenced in function _main
```

Same questions.

```
MSVCRTD.lib(gs_report.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__IsDebuggerPresent@0 referenced in function ___raise_securityfailure 
MSVCRTD.lib(error.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__IsDebuggerPresent@0
```

How do I look at the contents of these lib files, and see which obj files they contain, and which functions each of those contain?

There are lots more errors in `MSVCRTD.lib`

I hope someone can give me some guidance on finding the cause of all these errors.

Thanks - Rowan

Comment: A very simple google search ... [LNK2019](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/799kze2z(v=vs.100).aspx) - [LNK2001](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa234493(v=vs.60).aspx)

Comment: BTW all those linker errors mean that you are not linking  some mandatory resource: DLL, lib or whatever is needed by your code.

Comment: Yes, I have worked that out, but how do I know which DLL or lib contains the functions I need, and what the signature of the function in my code is, compared to the signature of the function in the library (I get the impression that the problem is often not that the function is completely missing, but that its signature is somewhat different).

Comment: Is an XY problem. If you use a function you must know which is the lib/dll or whatever that has the requred code. Same thing for headers that interface to the resource: into those .h files you have the correct prototype of functions.

Comment: Most of the code I'm using was not written by me. It was written either by Maxim (OneWire Public Domain Library) or by MS (winUSB). The guys who write the code presumably knew which library they were using, but I don't. Now I need to get the program to build - that's what I'm looking for help with.

Comment: I still need to know how to interpret the error messages. What do all those underscores, and numbers preceded by '@' mean? Thanks - Rowan

Comment: I'm not a VS exepert. BTW AFAIK "C" linkage add underscore to function names.